# onload not working after i use $.mobile.changePage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I will change page by  $.mobile.changePage with code

```
 $.mobile.changePage("profile.html", { transition : "slide"},false);
```

topage profile.html code

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function func()
{
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="String"
}
</script>
</head>
 <body onload="func()">
<div id="d"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript code

```
function func()
{
document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="String"
}
```

not work ,How to resolve?

Comment: Any error in your console?

Comment: @dholakiyaankit No error

Comment: I have read somewhere that events should me written in lowercase onload="func()"

Comment: @user2648239 I try both onLoad and onload . it not work

Comment: put ; after document.getElementByI....

Comment: @user2648239 i put ; it not work . the problem is not there.

Comment: can u paste your full profile.html code?

Comment: You wrote `onloal` instead of `onload`

Comment: If I remember right $.mobile.changePage is a ajax request. So it doesn't load anything between <head></head>. Try putting your javascript code in your <body>.

Comment: @eric.itzhak i write wrong to edit

Comment: try what @user2389688 suggested.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/), the `reloadPage` option is initially false which means that the page will not be reloaded, hence the `onload` event of the current document won't be fired again.

To make your body `onload` event to work again, you will need to add this option and set its value to `true`:

```
var options={
    transition: "slide",
    reloadPage: true
};
$.mobile.changePage("profile.html", options, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile uses Ajax to load pages. When first page is loaded, all tags and codes inside `<html>` are loaded. However, when you change page or load another html file, it loads only first page div `data-role=page` neglecting all tags and js outisde that div.

If you have any extra JS code, place it inside page div `data-role="page"`.

```
<div data-role="page">
  <script>
    document.getElementById("d").innerHTML="String"
  </script>
</div>
```